# Git: How to get a list of users and how many lines of code they've written

Tags: git

I wrote/stole a script some time ago to find out the current "owner" of a particular file that's in a Git repo.

```
#!/bin/bash
git blame --line-porcelain "$@" | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

It shows the results from `git blame` and sorts it by how many lines each user has modified.

The result looks something like this:

```
 125 Joe
  16 Fred
  16 Alice
   7 Jane
   4 Bob
```

My question is, how can I modify this script to recurse over an entire repo as opposed to a single file?

Comment: In my experience current "owners" are usually maintainers who do not edit much as opposed to the original author.  Here Fred may be the actual owner if Joe left the company.

Comment: I definitely agree. The numbers alone aren't a representation of who is currently maintaining the file, but it's a good start to determine who may know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list all files in Git using `git ls-tree`.

The following does what your script does, but over all files on the `master` branch.

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only | xargs -I {} git blame --line-porcelain {} | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: This is really good! The ls-tree command is really useful :) As an off   comment, how annoying is the Mac xargs when you have to define -I {} in each xargs command!

Comment: @Brad, Daniel What do you mean exactly? I'm getting "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence". Has it something to do with the comment you and Brad made?